# Can't access dashboard after 4.8.1 automatic upgrade

Tags: admin, updates, admin-bar, automatic-updates

I’ve had an automatic update to 4.8.1 (on local, staging and production-sites) on thursday the 3rd of August and since it is no longer possible to access the admin dashboard.

[image: Admin bar in current state]

In the header, i have the impression that i've lost administration capabilities although they are correctly configured in the database. As you can see, no additional menus are accessible from the admin-bar.

I’ve read through the thread for the 4.8 update and followed all hints (emptying browser cache, disabling plugins/themes (i get the white screen of death when doing so), troubleshooting in browser for JS errors, copying a fresh copy of WP, enabling troubleshooting in wp-config.php,…)

Also checked this link : https://blog.templatetoaster.com/wordpress-4-8-issues/ where they mention this issue, but not how to fix it unfortunately

I tried to add a new admin in phpMyAdmin but same outcome as above.

Is there something else I have forgotten ?

Many thanks for any additional hints !

Comment: Hi Le Conseil Informatique, Have you tried to check if your database access is working ? Maybe you just have a problem with your SQL server ?
What is your server configuration ? Paul

Comment: If you get the white screen of death it means that you have a php error somewhere. It might or might not be related to your problem, but you should look into your error log and try to fix it first

Comment: Hi @PaulHunault Accessing DB is functional on all instances. Server config's as follows :  Dev : MySQL 5.6.17/ PHP 7.0.3, Staging : MariaDB 10.1.26/ PHP 5.6.30 & Prod : MySQL 5.5.57/ PHP  7.0

Comment: Hi @MarkKaplun, checked error logs but there are only 2 errors for plugins, one concerning WP Jobmanager, the other BrokenLinkChecker. Disabling these does not change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any technical answer to my problem but what I did was to roll back to a backup of my database (which means I'll have to rewrite some of the stuff I've lost, but it'll save me time in the end I think)

The WP version is 4.8.1, theme is functional, all extensions are enabled and everything works on dev server, go figure.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the first place to look is the error log. That will usually point you to an error in a plugin.

You can disable an individual plugin by renaming it's folder. You can quickly disable all plugins by renaming the plugins folder. If you rename the entire plugin folder, then create a new plugins folder, and move individual plugin's folders into the new folder, thereby enabling them. The 'bad' plugin will cause the error to reoccur.

It is possible that a theme is causing the problem. Use the same technique to quickly disable your theme...that will cause WP to use the default theme.

Comment: Hi @RickHellewell. Followed you're instructions but nothing does it. When switching to default theme, white page of death occurs (see comment above @MarkKaplun). When switching back to default on my dev server, I've now even partially lost CSS of my child theme :(

Comment: Let me add to this that I have several websites using the same theme (Avada) and who updated themselves to 4.8.1 and none of theme present the same malfunctions.

Comment: Do you see anything in the error log when you get the "WSOD"? Have you tried WP_DEBUG = true  in the wp-config.php file and then look at the error log? If other sites are using the same theme, then perhaps the problem site has different plugins enabled?

Comment: Nothing more then stated in comment to Mark Kaplun above. I have found a solution in meantime though. Please see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms, but not in the exact same circumstances. I my case it was a migration (same website URL, but different host). Here is how it happened and got fixed so that hopefully it is useful to someone else.

In the process of the migration, I wanted to change the database prefix from `wp_` to `newprefix_`. So I changed wp-config.php accordingly, and before injecting the database, I opened the .sql file that was exported from the previous host, and changed all occurrences of `` `wp_ `` to `` `newprefix_ ``. Turns out some stuff shouldn't have to be replaced like that, because that's when, like you, I could log in, but not access Wordpress' admin pages.

I could regain access to them when I restored wp-config.php and the original database.

As for changing the prefix, I did it afterward with the fine [iThemes Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) plugin (this feature is a bit hidden. You have to go to Admin page > Security > Settings > Advanced > Change Database Table Prefix).